# Is there a way in ASP.NET to build API integration test the same way we do on ASP.NET Core with TestServer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am currently working on an ASP.NET project in .NET Framework and I want to build an integration test calling my API.

More precisely, I want to create an `HTTPClient`, that I can pass to my proxy which will then allow me to make so calls on my controller. I expect that my GET method of my controller is reached and that I get in return my object AssignmentDTO. I wrote the test below to test the attribute Description of that object.

I have to precise that I need to pass an Authorization. The one used in my company is OAuth2, but from Postman I used a basic Authorization and it works fine. So I do it by adding a value in the default header : `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic xxxxxxx");`

Here is my Get method in my controller :

```
        [ServiceAspect(Access.CanAccessTheApplication)]
        [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, typeof(AssignmentDTO), Description ="The TrainingRegistration name.")]
        [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, typeof(void), Description = "No data found.")]
        [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, typeof(IEnumerable<Message>))]
        [Route("")]
        [ActionName("GetAll")]
        public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {
            var dto = new AssignmentDTO()
            {
                Description = "blabla",
                ActivityId = 5,
                Id = 10
            };

            return Ok(dto);
        }
```

I found many things on the web, and some suggest to use OWIN to create a self-host API. This is what I use here.

```
        [TestMethod]
        public async Task T004_Get_CallThroughProxy()
        {
            //create client here
            HttpClient client = null;

            string baseAddress = "http://localhost:44305/";
            using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: baseAddress))
            {
                // Create HttpClient and make a request to api/values 
                client = new HttpClient();

                //Act
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Basic {credential}");
                var proxy = new TNPCoreInterfaceClient(client) { BaseUrl = "http://" };

                //Assert
                var result = await proxy.TrainingRegistration_GetAllAsync();
                Assert.AreEqual("blabla", result.Description);
            }
        }
```

Where the startup class is :

```
    public class Startup
    {
        // This code configures Web API. The Startup class is specified as a type
        // parameter in the WebApp.Start method.
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
        {
            // Configure Web API for self-host. 
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            //changed UseWebApi to use
            appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
        }
    }
```

the `TNPCoreInterfaceClient` is an auto generated proxy that shouldn't be a source of problem :

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<AssignmentDTO> TrainingRegistration_GetAllAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var urlBuilder_ = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            urlBuilder_.Append(BaseUrl != null ? BaseUrl.TrimEnd('/') : "").Append("/interface/trainingregistration/v1");
    
            var client_ = _httpClient;
            var disposeClient_ = false;
            try
            {
                using (var request_ = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage())
                {
                    request_.Method = new System.Net.Http.HttpMethod("GET");
                    request_.Headers.Accept.Add(System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));
    
                    PrepareRequest(client_, request_, urlBuilder_);
                    var url_ = urlBuilder_.ToString();
                    request_.RequestUri = new System.Uri(url_, System.UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                    PrepareRequest(client_, request_, url_);
    
                    var response_ = await client_.SendAsync(request_, System.Net.Http.HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    var disposeResponse_ = true;
                    try
                    {
                        var headers_ = System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary(response_.Headers, h_ => h_.Key, h_ => h_.Value);
                        if (response_.Content != null && response_.Content.Headers != null)
                        {
                            foreach (var item_ in response_.Content.Headers)
                                headers_[item_.Key] = item_.Value;
                        }
    
                        ProcessResponse(client_, response_);
    
                        var status_ = (int)response_.StatusCode;
                        if (status_ == 200)
                        {
                            var objectResponse_ = await ReadObjectResponseAsync<AssignmentDTO>(response_, headers_).ConfigureAwait(false);
                            if (objectResponse_.Object == null)
                            {
                                throw new RestException("Response was null which was not expected.", status_, objectResponse_.Text, headers_, null);
                            }
                            return objectResponse_.Object;
                        }
                        else
                        if (status_ == 404)
                        {
                            string responseText_ = ( response_.Content == null ) ? string.Empty : await response_.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                            throw new RestException("No data found.", status_, responseText_, headers_, null);
                        }
                        else
                        if (status_ == 400)
                        {
                            var objectResponse_ = await ReadObjectResponseAsync<System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Message>>(response_, headers_).ConfigureAwait(false);
                            if (objectResponse_.Object == null)
                            {
                                throw new RestException("Response was null which was not expected.", status_, objectResponse_.Text, headers_, null);
                            }
                            throw new RestException<System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Message>>("A server side error occurred.", status_, objectResponse_.Text, headers_, objectResponse_.Object, null);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var responseData_ = response_.Content == null ? null : await response_.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false); 
                            throw new RestException("The HTTP status code of the response was not expected (" + status_ + ").", status_, responseData_, headers_, null);
                        }
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (disposeResponse_)
                            response_.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (disposeClient_)
                    client_.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

When I run the project, the "manual" test with Postman. I call the url `https://localhost:44305/interface/trainingregistration/v1` with Postman and with the specified Auth and I got the right DTO in return.

When I run the test in debug, It crashes on `client_.SendAsync(...` in `TrainingRegistration_GetAllAsync` and I get the error message :

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'An invalid request URI was provided. The request URI must either be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set.'

EDIT (Jan 27 2021) :
For those wondering, I never succeeded doing it at that time.

Comment: What is ASP.Net Standard? Do you mean ASP.Net on .Net Framework?

Comment: The (invalid) URL you end out with is `http:/interface/trainingregistration/v1` - see https://dotnetfiddle.net/5CLp8l

Comment: Basic debugging would have led you to the line `urlBuilder_.Append(BaseUrl != null ? BaseUrl.TrimEnd('/') : "").Append("/interface/trainingregistration/v1");`

Comment: - yes I mean ASP.Net on .Net Framework -> corrected.

Comment: ok thanks for the suggestions I'll follow this lead about the URL and keep you posted